# redux withrouter not working with react. It will render new page but won't render with new state/props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-dom, react-router-redux

The handleSubmitSearch function calls a thunk (which calls a fetch call) to be rendered on the new page. This function works without router, but using router, the handleSubmitSearch is never even called (the console log doesn't fire, and neither do the fetch calls). I have also tried using numerous life cycle methods, like componenetWillUpdate, componentShouldUpdate, componentwillreceiveprops etc. I've also tried installing the connected-react-router npm module which didn't fix the problem.

I've been googling this problem for hours and I can't seem to figure out why none of my fixes are working.

```js
export class SearchDirections extends React {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      origin: '',
      departure: '',
      mode: ''
    }
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  };

  handleRadioChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    mode: e.target.value
  });
}

  handleSubmitSearch = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('test')
    await this.props.getNewDirections(this.state.origin, this.state.departure, this.state.mode)
    if(this.props.direction) {
    let startCoordinates = this.props.directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_location 
    let endCoordinates = this.props.directions.routes[0].legs[0].end_location
    await this.props.displayWeatherStart(startCoordinates)
  }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmitSearch}>
        <input
        placeholder='enter origin' 
        className='origin'
        name='origin' 
        value={this.state.origin}
        onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
        />
        <input 
        placeholder='enter departure' 
        className='departure'
        name='departure' 
        value={this.state.departure}
        onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}       
        />
      <Link to='/directions'> 
       <button className='submit-btn'>submit</button>
       </Link>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input 
              className='radio'
              type='checkbox' 
              value='transit' 
              name='radio' 
              checked={this.state.mode === 'transit'}
              onChange={this.handleRadioChange}
              />
              transit
           </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input 
              className='radio'
              type='checkbox' 
              value='walking' 
              name='radio'
              checked={this.state.mode === 'walking'}
              onChange={this.handleRadioChange}
            />
              walking
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>  
            <label>
              <input 
              className='radio'
              type='checkbox' 
              value='bicycling' 
              name='radio'
              checked={this.state.mode === 'bicycling'}
              onChange={this.handleRadioChange}
              />
              bicycling
            </label>
          </li> 
          <li> 
            <label>
              <input 
              className='radio'
              type='checkbox'  
              value='driving' 
              name='radio'
              checked={this.state.mode === 'driving'}
              onChange={this.handleRadioChange}
              />
              driving
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </form>
    )
  }
}


export const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  directions: state.directions,
  startWeather: state.startWeather,
  isLoading: state.isLoading
});

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  getNewDirections: (origin, departure, mode) => dispatch(getCurrentDirections(origin, departure, mode,)),
  displayWeatherStart: (city) => dispatch(getCurrentWeather(city)),
});

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchDirections));
```

Comment: I noticed, you haven't given any type to the submit button, that might be the reason of the function not getting called, give `type=submit` to the button and then try once.

Comment: Have you tried putting a break point on `handleSubmitSearch` function so you can step through it?

Comment: unfortunately adding type='submit' on the button didnt work @AnimeshSaraswat

Comment: @OliverRadini I put a debugger in handleSubmitSearch and it never stopped the code

Comment: @KatieShamus just to check, did you have webtools open? It doesn't hit break points otherwise

Comment: as far as i understand your code, as soon as the submit button is hit, it redirect's you to **directions** page?

Answer (score 0):

Setting it up this way might do the trick since you need `withRouter`'s (HOC) features to be passed to your component:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(SearchDirections));
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that you try again working with the connected-react-router npm module.  In addition to this module, try using the npm [Redux Form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-form) module to handle your form.  Redux Form has a decorator that allows you to connect your form component to Redux.  This decorator, called [reduxForm](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/reduxform.md/), has many properties including **onSubmit** and, what I think you need to get a new page rendered while using a router, **onSubmitSuccess**.  Here's a good article on using [Redux Form](https://medium.com/@wlodarczyk_j/tutorial-creating-a-basic-form-with-redux-form-2f8cd51cd40).